# Avoid eager_loading when accessing a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My problem is that I use this query  :

```
@questions = Question.includes(:answer).joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id AND answers.user_id= 1').select('answers.*, questions.*')
```

And then it produces these 2 mysql queries. The problem is the second query fetch the answers for every users.

```
 1.Question Load (2.7ms)  SELECT answers.*, questions.* FROM "questions" LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id AND answers.user_id= 1
 2.Answer Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1)
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Get every questions and their relation "answer"

But I only want answer from a specific user.

Comment: @questions = @user.answers.includes(:questions).collect(&:questions).flatten

Comment: just tried. It only returns questions with answer.

Answer (score 1):

Second query fetch answers not for each users. It fetch them for all questions (look at condition in query). If you want to avoid it then just remove `includes` or try to add conditions as described [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes).

Comment: Yes but a already fetched the answers with the first query.

But do you have any clue on how to do it ?

I'm stuck on it since 2 days...

I want  all questions with answer from a specific user.

Comment: I want to add a where clause on the second query. 

Because if I add it on the first one, question with no answer will not be selected